# Verilog: Implementation Using Primitive Modules vs. Bit-wise Operators

Tags: verilog

The textbook I'm reading implements 1-bit adders using built-in primitive modules:

```
module yAdder1(z, cout, a, b, cin);
     output[0:0] z, cout;
     input[0:0] a, b, cin;
     wire[0:0] tmp, outL, outR;

     xor left_xor(tmp, a, b);
     xor right_xor(z, cin, tmp);
     and left_and(outL, a, b);
     and right_and(outR, tmp, cin);
     or my_or(cout, outR, outL);
endmodule
```

But why not use bit-wise operators? Seems simpler.

```
module yAdder1(z, cout, a, b, cin);
     output[0:0] z, cout;
     input[0:0] a, b, cin;

     assign z = (a ^ b) ^ cin;
     assign cout = (a & b) | ((a ^ b) & cin);
endmodule
```

Unless bit-wise operators implicitly use  primitive modules?

Comment: heck, why not use a '+' operator while you're at it :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use Boolean operators?

```
assign Z = (a != b) != c; 
assign cout = (a && b) || ((a != b) && cin);
```

All three options are functionally equivalent ways of implementing a standard full adder.

The simple answer to your question (and to my rhetorical one) is probably simply that your textbook is trying to build up knowledge, starting with low level design and working up.

In the Verilog module we teach at uni, we start off with primitives (gate level), then move on to Verilog bitwise and Boolean operators, then move to higher levels of abstraction (e.g. `{cout, Z} = a + b + cin`). We find that this helps introduce people who may not have a strong programming or digital background into FPGA design, allowing them to get a feel for how higher and higher levels of abstraction work.

Comment: Ah I see, Gate (Structural) Level abstraction vs Functional and Algorithmic Level (Behavioral) abstraction. Each with their own pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

No one in industry uses bit-wise models. Less typing, equivalent functionality. Perhaps more optimized in the simulator.